# why I'm not allowed to uninstall an app on my developer edition salesforce account?

Tags: appexchange, app

I've installed an app from AppExchange Marketplace , now I intend to uninstall it but doesn't allow me to do that.Is there any dependency to permissions? what must I do?

[image: I've attached the error message image]

Comment: Did you read the error message. Seems pretty clear to me. Unassign the permission set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Eric said in the comments, you just need to unassign the Permission Set called `Fast Forms Permissions`.

To do this, go to:

> Setup > Administer > Manage Users > Permission Sets

Click the `Fast Forms Permissions` permission set, then click the <kbd>Manage Assignments</kbd> button. Tick everyone and click <kbd>Remove Assignments</kbd>. You could then be able to uninstall the package as you've done previously.

Comment: @Juliana. Great! If you mark this question as answered, it'll close the question down and potentially help others in the future. :)

Comment: sure, how can I mark this question as answered , is there any icon specified?

Comment: @Juliana just press the little tick  mark.

Comment: I did . tnx Dan